# Is it okay to make up your own words at times?

Tags: formality

Let's say you're writing an essay and you want to convey a message as concisely as possible with a time-constraint on your hands, and you don't really get the right words.
Is it okay to make up words to express what you want to say, as in "the stock prices dropped so low,the entire company was 'blue-d' out" (as opposed to severely demotivated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, if you expect that all of your audience or readers will understand your meaning.  If there are no other constraints it doesn't matter if they will understand you or not.  Be careful to consider the risk versus the rewards when you are publishing to a wide audience.  Some people may get blued out about this answer, but I won't give out any shorts because of it.

Comment: @abhiii5459: Suffice it to say, in light of the question being closed, that many people would not agree with this answer and you absolutely should use great care. It's certainly appropriate for closing as the topic is definitely "argumentative" and quite "subjective".

Comment: "give out any shorts": what does that mean? What's a 'short'?

Comment: Mitch, "shorting" a stock is a common reaction to a company being blued out.

Comment: This answer is completely harbile, its covers everything in the question and will plobtabuly not be the cause of flabstabulation amongst readers.